# Changing UITableViewController to UITableView crashes app

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have just changed from a `UITableViewController` to a `UITableView`, and everything is working fine, with the exception of the search bar, which when tapping on a key on the keyboard will crash the app with the error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier rideCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

I haven't changed anything in terms of the code. Someone suggested changing:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("rideCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RideCell
```

to:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("rideCell") as! RideCell
```

but that didn't help at all.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

Here is my code as requested:

class InitalViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

```
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

var rideName = ""

var parkPassed: Park!

var searchResults = NSArray()

var loadingIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
var backgroundLabel = LabelWithInsets()

var refreshSpinner = UIRefreshControl()

func handleRefresh(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
    DataManager.sharedInstance.loadRides(parkPassed.name!.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: ""))

    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    backgroundLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    backgroundLabel.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x424242)
    backgroundLabel.numberOfLines = 0

    refreshSpinner.addTarget(self, action: "handleRefresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    tableView.addSubview(refreshSpinner)
    //refreshControl = refreshSpinner

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar
    self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, CGRectGetHeight(searchBar.frame))

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x0096FF)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "updateTableView", name: "onRidesLoadedNotification", object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "displayError", name: "onRidesLoadFailedNotification", object: nil)        
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if DataManager.sharedInstance.rideArray.count == 0 {
        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None

        loadingIndicator.frame = CGRectMake((view.bounds.width / 2) - 25, (view.bounds.height / 2) - 50, 50, 50)
        loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
        view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
        loadingIndicator.startAnimating()

        backgroundLabel.text = "Loading rides..."
        backgroundLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, (view.bounds.height / 2) - 80, view.bounds.width, 30)
        view.addSubview(backgroundLabel)
    }

    DataManager.sharedInstance.loadRides(parkPassed.name!.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: ""))

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: false)

    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("favourites") != nil {
        let tempFavourites: NSArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("favourites")!
        favouritesArray = tempFavourites.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
    }
}

@IBAction func dismiss(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func updateTableView() {
    tableView.reloadData()

    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine
    loadingIndicator.removeFromSuperview()
    backgroundLabel.removeFromSuperview()
}

func displayError() {
    loadingIndicator.removeFromSuperview()
    backgroundLabel.removeFromSuperview()

    backgroundLabel.text = "Failed to load rides. Please check your internet connection."
    backgroundLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, (view.bounds.height / 2) - 80, view.bounds.width, 60)
    view.addSubview(backgroundLabel)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    println(DataManager.sharedInstance.rideArray.count)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("rideCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RideCell

    var ride: Ride

    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView {
        ride = DataManager.sharedInstance.getRideByName(searchResults[indexPath.row].name)!
    } else {
        ride = DataManager.sharedInstance.rideAtLocation(indexPath.row)!
    }

    cell.rideNameLabel.text = ride.name

    var dateSinceUpdate = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(ride.updated!)
    var secondsSinceUpdate = Int(dateSinceUpdate)
    var timeSinceUpdate = printSecondsConvert(secondsSinceUpdate)

    cell.updatedLabel.text = timeSinceUpdate

    if ride.waitTime == "Closed" {
        cell.waitTimeLabel.text = ride.waitTime!
        cell.timeBackgroundView.backgroundColor = getColorFromNumber(80)
        cell.waitTimeLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 13)
    } else {
        cell.waitTimeLabel.text = "\(ride.waitTime!)m"
        cell.timeBackgroundView.backgroundColor = getColorFromNumber(ride.waitTime!.toInt()!)
        cell.waitTimeLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 17)
    }

    AsyncImageLoader.sharedLoader().cancelLoadingURL(cell.rideImageView.imageURL)
    cell.rideImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Unloaded")
    cell.rideImageView.imageURL = NSURL(string: ride.rideImageSmall!)

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView {
        return searchResults.count
    } else {
        return DataManager.sharedInstance.rideArray.count
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! RideCell!

    rideName = currentCell.rideNameLabel.text!

    performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetail", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "showDetail") {
        var viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController

        viewController.currentRide = DataManager.sharedInstance.getRideByName(rideName)
        viewController.parkPassed = parkPassed
    }
}

func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: NSString) {
    let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[cd] %@", searchText) //Use either contains or beginswith
    searchResults = (DataManager.sharedInstance.rideArray as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(resultPredicate)
}

func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController!, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String!) -> Bool {
    self.filterContentForSearchText(searchString)
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 71
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {
    var cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! RideCell

    let favourite = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "          ") { action, index in
        if favouritesArray.containsObject(cell.rideNameLabel.text!) {
            favouritesArray.removeObject(cell.rideNameLabel.text!)
        } else {
            favouritesArray.addObject(cell.rideNameLabel.text!)
        }
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(favouritesArray, forKey: "favourites")
        tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
    }

    if favouritesArray.containsObject(cell.rideNameLabel.text!) {
        favourite.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Unfavourite")!)
    } else {
        favourite.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Favourite")!)
    }

    return [favourite]
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
}
```

}

Comment: is `rideCell` a custom cell made in IB?

Comment: Did you register your cell with the tableView using  `func registerNib(_ nib: UINib,forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String)`

Comment: Did you put the custom cell in the class inspector in interface builder?

Comment: Yeah, and the cell identifier is correct. Everything works perfectly until you go to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call next code in `viewDidLoad` method of view controller that contains your table view:
If you created `RideCell` in xib:

```
tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "RideCell", bundle: nil),
     forCellReuseIdentifier: "rideCell")
```

If you created `RideCell` in code:

```
tableView.registerClass(RideCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "rideCell")
```

Comment: Doesn't fix the issue unfortunately. Adding that code just produces an empty table view. Like I mentioned, everything works fine until I try to search for something. Surely nothing would work at all if it was an issue with the way the cell was registered?

Comment: @user3746428 this code resolves the crash: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier rideCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'`  Empty table view  is another problem, that I think should be considered separately.

Comment: But adding the code that you suggested still crashes the app in the same way, but also leaves the table view empty.

Comment: May be you need provide whole code in your question.

Comment: @user3746428 try to use the same code as in my example, but put `self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView` instead of `tableView` or call this code for both tableViews.

Comment: That gives me `reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CA426F3A-BE3D-4EA1-A153-9F0F4FFA1C08/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/A20B346E-599C-4FBE-AC14-52C62C41ADCC/App Name.app> (loaded)' with name 'RideCell''`

Comment: @user3746428 Do you have file `RideCell.xib` in your project?

Comment: No, I have RideCell.Swift.

Comment: @user3746428 in this case use my second approach: `tableView.registerClass(RideCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "rideCell")`

Comment: That seems to work, but I'm now getting a crash on the line `cell.rideNameLabel.text = ride.name`, with the error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. This wasn't an issue I was having before I changed to a table view.

Comment: @user3746428 I think you was using prototypal cell in storyboard. That's why it worked. But now you implement cell separately. I think you need create `RideCell.xib` class and connect it to `RideCell.swift`. After that you need use my first approach: `registerNib....`

Comment: Ah, so I can't use a prototype cell with a `UITableView`?

Comment: @user3746428 you can, but only for usual table views. For searchResultsTableView you can't.

Answer (score 0):

In your `viewDidLoad` you have to register the custom cell to your `UITableView` using this function:

```
func registerNib(_ nib: UINib,forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String)
```

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately. I've added my code if it helps at all.